# Negate assert_difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, functional-testing

I am doing functional tests and just discovered assert_difference, as in:

```
assert_difference('Account.count') do
  post :create, :account => @account.attributes
end
```

Is there a counterpart, which would check if *Account.count* has **not** changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assert_no_difference(expression, message = nil, &block)
```

[From the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions.html): "Assertion that the numeric result of evaluating an expression is not changed before and after invoking the passed in block."

Comment: or `assert_difference("...", 0)`.